# Databricks: how to convert the values of the rows to array type

Tags: python, databricks

suppose I have the following data frame
col1
a
b
c

I would like to convert the values to a arrayType variable 
['a','b','c']

any idea ?

Comment: anyone has the idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you have a data frame of `pandas` or `pyspark` in databricks as below.

```
import pandas as pd

# pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

# pyspark dataframe in databricks
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

So just for pandas dataframe to select the `Col1` column to convert to array, the code as below.

```
pandas_array = df['Col1'].array
# <PandasArray>
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
# Length: 3, dtype: object
py_list = list(pandas_array)
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Or you want to convert the `Col1` column of a PySpark dataframe to array, as the code below.

```
rows = sdf.select(f.collect_list('Col1').alias('arr')).collect()
row = rows[0]
arr = row['arr']
```

[image]

Ofcouse, you also can convert a PySpark dataframe to a pandas dataframe, then to do the first code conversion.

```
df2 = sdf.toPandas()
pd_arr = df2['Col1'].array
```